# Robot Frame work: Error While running .robot file in python interpreter using robot.run (windows environment)

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to execute **Run_Keyword.robot** made with **RIDE** file which is in directory 'Robot' from python interpreter and getting following error. I am able to run this **.py** file from **cmd** without any error and it gives expected results. What can be the reason for this. I am a newbie to **Robot Framework**. Please help with this.

```
from robot import run
run('C:\\Users\\uvijayac\\Desktop\\Robot')
```

The Error I am getting is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uvijayac\Desktop\Robot\rf.py", line 27, in <module>
    run_tests()
  File "C:\Users\uvijayac\Desktop\Robot\rf.py", line 23, in run_tests
    report=report_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\run.py", line 471, in run
    return RobotFramework().execute(*datasources, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 83, in execute
    return self._execute(list(arguments), options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self._report_error(unicode(err), help=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 110, in _report_error
    self._logger.error(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\loggerhelper.py", line 59, in error
    self.write(msg, 'ERROR')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\loggerhelper.py", line 62, in write
    self.message(Message(message, level, html))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\logger.py", line 109, in message
    logger.message(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 66, in message
    self._writer.error(msg.message, msg.level, clear=self._running_test)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 142, in error
    self._highlight('[ ', level, ' ] ' + message, error=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 158, in _highlight
    self._write(before, newline=False, error=error)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 154, in _write
    stream.flush()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
>>>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have called the filename?

run('C:\\Users\\uvijayac\\Desktop\\Robot\\Run_Keyword.robot')

Comment: Your traceback indicates that you are not doing something as simple as you say. What is the value of report_file? Have you tried calling run without the 'report' argument?

Comment: ya.. but I get similar error when I run the given code. Report file was included in my initial code. I tried to localise the error. It occurred when I called the run method with just path as argument.